# How to gradually train with more and more classes?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to create an incremental classifier that will get trained on data containing n classes for some set number of epochs, then n+m classes for a set number of epochs, then n+m+k, etc, where each successive set of classes contains the previous set as a subset.

In order to do this without having to train the model, save it, manually edit the graph, re-train, repeat, I'm simply defining all the weights I will need to classify the entire set of classes, but keeping the weights corresponding to unseen classes frozen at 0 until the classifier is introduced to those classes.

My strategy for this is to define a placeholder that is fed in an array of Boolean values defining whether or not some given set of weights are trainable.

Relevant code below:

```
output_train = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (num_incremental_grps), name         = "output_train")
.
.
.
weights = []
biases = []
for i in range(num_incremental_grps):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batch_size, classes_per_grp]),         
    trainable=tf.cond(tf.equal(output_train[i], tf.constant(1)),lambda: tf.constant(True), lambda: tf.constant(False)))
    weights.append(W)
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([classes_per_grp]), trainable=tf.cond(tf.equal(output_train[i], 
    tf.constant(1)), lambda:tf.constant(True), lambda: tf.constant(False)))
    biases.append(b)

out_weights = tf.stack(weights, axis=1).reshape((batch_size, -1))
out_biases = tf.stack(biases, axis=1).reshape((batch_size, -1))
outputs = tf.identity(tf.matmul(inputs, out_weights) + out_biases, name='values')
.
.
.
# Will change this to an array that progressively updates as classes are added.
output_trainable = np.ones(num_incremental_grps, dtype=bool)
.
.
.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for iteration in range(iterations):
            X_batch, y_batch = batch.getBatch()
            fd={X: X_batch, y: y_batch, training: True, output_train: output_trainable}
            _, loss_val = sess.run([training_op, loss], feed_dict=fd)
```

This returns the error message

```
Using a 'tf.Tensor' as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of 
`if t:` to test if a tensor is defined,and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute 
subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

I've tried tinkering around with this, like making the initial placeholder datatype tf.bool instead of tf.int32. I've also tried just feeding in a slice of the tensor into the 'trainable' argument in the weights/biases like this

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batch_size, classes_per_grp]), trainable=output_variable[i])
```

but I get the same error message. I'm not sure how to proceed from here, aside from trying a completely different approach to updating the number of predictable classes. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `tf.cond` takes a decision based on a single boolean — much like an `if` statement. What you want here is to make a choice per element of your tensor.

You could use `tf.where` to fix that problem, but then you will run into another one, which is that `trainable` is not a property that you can fix at runtime, it is part of the definition of a variable. If a variable will be trained at some point, perhaps not at the beginning but definitely later, then it must be `trainable`.

I would suggest to take a much simpler route: define `output_train` to be an array of `tf.float32`

```
output_train = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(num_incremental_grps), name="output_train")
```

then later simply multiply your weights and variables with this vector.

```
W = tf.Variable(...)
W = W * output_train
...
```

Provide values of `1` to `output_train` where you want training to happen, `0` otherwise.

Be careful to *also* mask your loss to ignore output from unwanted channels, because event though they now always output 0, that may still affect your loss. For example,

```
logits = ...
logits = tf.matrix_transpose(tf.boolean_mask(
  tf.matrix_transpose(logits ),
  output_train == 1))
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=labels)
```